# How can i get the session ID which came as a part of client hello in C, SSL_SESSION_get_id just returns negotiated session ID

Tags: c, openssl

I am trying to retrieve session ID which client has presented as a part of client hello in a resumed session, Unfortunately i have access to only application layer, Is there a way i can extract it from SSL structure or any Openssl API available for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set message callback using the API [SSL_CTX_set_msg_callback](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_msg_callback.html). This will give all the handshake messages which are sent or received. In this, you can try to parse `ClientHello` message and retrieve the `Session ID`.